# How to count how many duplicate keys are in array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

Is is to possible to get how many 'a' are in array?

```
$array = array( 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're just looking for `a` values, you could also use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
$array = array( 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c' );
$count = count(array_keys($array, 'a', true));
echo "Found $count letter a's.";
```

Answer (score 11):

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)  is what you need

```
<?php
$array = array( 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c' );
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 4
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Haim is correct. However I have had some speed issues with array_count_values before. So if you already know what value you are checking for, and don't need the others. A loop and counter can be faster. I'd benchmark.

EDIT

That is, unless the array is smaller than 1000-10,000 items. Then it is probably too small to matter.